# When changing a Twitter handle, does Twitter auto-redirect new tweets?

Tags: twitter

We've recently changed our company name (more a variation of official name, but has the same effect). We want to change our Twitter handle to reflect this, the new handle is available and we can change it in the settings tab.

Before we do, so that there is no negative SEO/social implications, does anyone know whether Twitter will redirect tweets to our new handle if someone writes `@oldname`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Twitter won't redirect tweets to your new handle if someone tweets to your old handle. Your old handle will be left for grabs so anyone will be able to use it.

I suggest you take possession of your old handle (simply sign up as a new user with a different email address) and note in the description what your new handle is (and why).

That way, even if someone mistakenly uses your old handle (which is unlikely) you'll be notified of it since you'll be in control of it and you'll be able to answer with your new handle then.

Also, if you forget you've left a link to your old Twitter handle somewhere on the web, people will still be able to find you.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a new account, you can also create a search for the old handle and save that search in your new handle. Use tweetdeck or any desktop based app for better usability.

Comment: hi ruben could you explain a bit more when you say 'create a search for the old handle and save that search in your new handle'

Comment: if your old id was samOld. You can search in twitter for samOld and save that search. Use tweetdeck to display that search as a column.